# C calling Fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran90

I am new to the site, and this looks like it may be a place to get some tips and help if any.

I am learning about "C calling Fortran subroutine", I have knowledge with C but not too much with Fortran.

Plus side: I've looked at some examples, and was able to compile a few.

Negative side: I am somewhat lost. I have a main program which can be designed using C or Fortran 90, and print_matrix.f and print_matrix.c.

Within the main.c program,
   - populate array of 1-9 of a matrix size 3 by 3
   - call the c function
   - call the fortran subrountine

I already have the populated side(it may not be accurate), but I am stuck on the subrountine. The output of fortran and C has to be the same which will output through the print_matrix.f90 and print_matrix.c using makefile. I need help with the calling subrountine part, I just don't know where to begin with that :(

I just need help, any will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you really limited to Fortran 90?  If you can use the features from the 2003 edition of the Fortran standard this interoperability between Fortran and C will be much easier.

Comment: Keep in mind that C and Fortran store matrices in different ways. In C the storage is row-major, which means that `mat[i][j]` and `mat[i][j+1]` are adjacent in memory. In Fortran a column-major storage is used, i.e. `mat(i,j)` and `mat(i+1,j)` are adjacent in memory. That means Fortran sees C arrays as transposed and vice versa and you have to keep this in mind when defining matrix dimensions and iterating over matrix elements in both languages.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, it's a little hard to tell exactly what your problem is.  But here's an example that works on my linux machine:

callf.c:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i=0;
  increment_(&i);
  printf("%d\n",i);
  return;
  }
```

increment.f90:

```
subroutine increment(n)
integer n
n=n+1
return
end subroutine
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -c callf.c
gfortran -c increment.f90
gcc callf.o increment.o -lgfortran
```

Result:

```
> ./a.out
1
```

The two hard parts are 1) getting the exact name of the function call and 2) knowing what flags are needed to link the two codes.  Re: 1) I knew to use "increment_" because, after compiling my FORTRAN code, I ran the "nm" utility on increment.o and found the name of the object was "increment_".  On some systems, you might see "INCREMENT", "_increment", or all sorts of other things.  Re: 2) Information should be available for whatever compiler you are using.  It varies alot.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain! I do understand what you have to a certain degree but alittle faded. What I've created in the code is for the C to call the Fortran subroutine. I've created a function inside the .c file, and a subroutine function inside the .f90 file. I was able to get the output of the C version, but cannot get the output for the Fortran version, which is where I am now stuck on. It could be something minor but I am uncertain. I am new to Fortran and I am just not understanding clearly on why the output is not coming out.

Comment: No problem.  Honestly, without seeing some of the actual code you are writing, I don't think I can say much more.  I kind of doubt anyone else will be able to either.  Can you show the code?

Comment: @bob.sacamento Any portable mixed C/C++ and Fortran code should use the `ISO_C_BINDING` mechanism in Fortran in order not to depend on specific name mangling or language type compatibility. There are lots of question and examples of using `ISO_C_BINDING` here on SO.